# converting to YYYYMMDD format with the value date posted from PHP

Tags: php, date

I have a date value posted from PHP using JQuery (`MMDDYYYY`) and I want to convert this date format to `YYYYMMDD` using PHP.

```
$fromDate=str_replace("'","''",trim($_POST['p']));
echo "-->".$year = substr($fromDate, 6, 4)."<br>";
echo "-->".$month = substr($fromDate, 0, 2)."<br>";
echo "-->".$date = substr($fromDate, 3, 2)."<br>";
echo $new_date = date( 'Ymd', strtotime($month, $date, $year ));
```

Suppose in the above code I have entered the date as `070122010`.The `new_date` in the last line gives me `20100714`. I don't know why it is giving today's date. I have tried both `mktime` and `strtotime`, but both are giving me the same result. The desired result is `20100712` (`YYYYMMDD`).

Comment: Ever thought of trying it out yourself?

Comment: If you know string manipulation functions in php you should be able to write your own.
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Comment: Sure wish I could edit posts. s/variable/parameter/g; s/Php/PHP/; s/Function/function/; s/Needed/needed; s/Format/format; s/$THIS_LAZY_POST//

Comment: @no: s/copypasta/copypasta/ Oh, wait...

Answer (score 5):

The [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function will do what you want, providing you have a PHP 5.3.0 or greater:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('mdY', '12312010');

echo $date->format('Ymd');
// 20101231

echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
// 2010-12-31

echo $date->format('Y-M-d');
//2010-Dec-31
```

Answer (score 4):

`strtotime($old_date)` won't work because `MMDDYYYY` is not a valid date string: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

```
preg_replace("/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})/","$3$1$2",$old_date);
```

or an even shorter version:

```
preg_replace("/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})/","$2$1",$old_date);
```

Comment: Since both formats contain MMDD, you can simplify your regex a bit

Comment: All you people seem to like a regex (I myself voted for the php5.3 DateTime::createFromFormat b.t.w.), but IF you go that route, please add some sane semi-validation: `"/((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([0-9]{4})/"`

Answer (score 3):

`strtotime` won't work because `MMDDYYYY` is not a valid date string:

```
preg_replace("/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})/","$3$1$2", $orig_date);
```

Comment: even shorter: `preg_replace("/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})/","$2$1", $orig_date);`

Comment: even shorter: `preg_replace("/(\d{4})(\d{4})/", "$2$1", $orig_date);` :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to tear apart the date.  All you need to do is move the year to the front.

```
$orig = '01022010';
$new = substr($orig,4).substr($orig,0,4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways:

```
$d = preg_replace("/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})/", "$2$1", $originalDate);
```

or

```
$d = substr($originalDate, 4, 4) . substr($originalDate, 0, 4);
```

If one of these makes more sense to you, I suggest you use that one. Otherwise, I suspect the second would be slightly faster though I haven't tested.

Answer (score 1):

```
function mmddyyyy_to_yyyymmdd ($input) {
    $monthdays = array(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31);
    if ( !preg_match('/\\A\\d{8}\\Z/', $input) ) {
        return false;
    }
    $month = (int)substr($input, 0, 2);
    $day   = (int)substr($input, 2, 2);
    $year  = (int)substr($input, 4);
    if ( $year % 4 == 0 and
         ( $year % 100 != 0 or $year % 400 == 0 )
         ) {
        $monthdays[1] = 29;
    }
    if ( $month < 1 or
         $month > 12 or
         $day < 1 or
         $day > $monthdays[$month-1]
         ) {
        return false;
    }
    if ( $month < 10 ) { $month = '0'.$month; }
    if ( $day < 10 ) { $day = '0'.$day; }
    while ( strlen($year) < 4 ) {
        $year = '0'.$year;
    }
    return $year.$month.$date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_date = date("Ymd", strtotime($old_date));
```

Comment: `date("Ymd", strtotime('12242010'))` should return `20101224` but it returns `19700101`

Comment: Indeed.. hadn't realized that. Sometimes you just put a little too much trust in something ;) (although strtotime() IS a gem of course!)

Comment: It is  returning '19691231' when i use the strtotime()

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = strptime('12242010','%m%d%Y');

$date = mktime(
 $data['tm_hour'],
 $data['tm_min'],
 $data['tm_sec'],
 $data['tm_mon']+1,
 $data['tm_mday'],
 $data['tm_year']+1900);

echo date('Ymd',$date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using substr would be faster: http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php

```
$orig="20072010"; // DDMMYYYY
$new=substr($orig,5,4)+substr($orig,3,2)+substr($orig,0,2); // YYYYMMDD
```

And it is worth reading this:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Answer (score -2):

This is my answer. At last I succeeded.

```
date( 'Ymd', mktime(0,0,0,$month, $date, $year ));
```